# I'm adding the data from the json file to my list, but the list is empty

Tags: json, flutter, dart, future

I'm pulling the json file from an API and trying to add it to the list, but the list is empty afterwards.

```
Future<List<Posts>> getPosts() async {
    var datas = await http.get(
        Uri.parse("https://www.reddit.com/r/TechNewsToday/top.json?count=20"));

    var jsonDatas = json.decode(datas.body);

    List<Posts> postList = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      var postJson = jsonDatas["data"]["children"][i];

      String subreddit = postJson["data"]["subreddit"];
      String title = postJson["data"]["title"];
      String thumbnail = postJson["data"]["thumbnail"];

      Posts post = Posts(title, thumbnail, subreddit);

      postList.add(post);
    }

    print(postList.length);

    return postList;
  }
```

Comment: try to print subreddit ,title  and thumbnail

Comment: I get the correct output in for, but outside of for the list is empty

Answer (score 0):

So when I tried this on my end I got a range error. Not sure where 7 comes from in your for loop but its probably safer to use the length of the `children` in the response. When I look at the json response, what you're trying to parse only has 5 items.

Maybe that changes, but all the more reason to not use a fixed number in your loop.

This works for me.

```
Future<List<Posts>> getPosts() async {
    var datas = await http.get(
        Uri.parse("https://www.reddit.com/r/TechNewsToday/top.json?count=20"));

    var jsonDatas = json.decode(datas.body);

    List<Posts> postList = [];

    // this is the actual length of what you're trying to parse
    final responseLength = jsonDatas["data"]["children"].length as int;

    for (int i = 0; i < responseLength; i++) {
      var postJson = jsonDatas["data"]["children"][i];

      String subreddit = postJson["data"]["subreddit"];
      String title = postJson["data"]["title"];
      String thumbnail = postJson["data"]["thumbnail"];

      Posts post = Posts(title, thumbnail, subreddit);

      postList.add(post);
    }

    print(postList.length);

    return postList;
  }
```